# Getting the GUID of an installed COM object

Tags: winapi, com, registry, 32bit-64bit, guid

I have a 32bit COM object that I want to use with 64bit PHP.

I am trying to follow the tutorial here:

http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

But I am stuck on "Locate your COM object GUID", as I have no idea where I can find out this information.

Does anyone know how I can find the GUID of the COM object?

Comment: Do you have a progid (like 'something.something')?

Comment: If `COM` is already registered (using regsvr32.exe or DllRegister()), then run `regedit.exe` and look under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and you'll see a long list of file extensions, just scroll down until u see a list of ProgIDs. Find the ProgID that relates to your COM and underneath you'll find the CLSID (GUID).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will at least have to know the ProgID of the COM component.  Something similar to "Word.Application", the string you pass to the COM() constructor.  Run Regedit.exe and look through the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for that string.  Open the node, the CLSID key's default value gives you the GUID you are looking for.

Comment: Or call the [CLSIDFromProgID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386.aspx) function in your code.