# Using a 32bit COM object in a 64bit environment:

Tags: winapi, com, registry, 32bit-64bit, guid

Trying to follow the Link below:

http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

It says: `Locate your COM object GUID under the HKey_Classes_Root\Wow6432Node\CLSID\[GUID]`

I could find the GUID of the COM component by this post. The GUID is shown on the picture below.

[Getting the GUID of an installed COM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112880/getting-the-guid-of-an-installed-com-object)

[image]

So the GUID is `{1797F52C-C5E2-4F41-B524-F5A107EA6453}` Now I'm looking for something named `{1797F52C-C5E2-4F41-B524-F5A107EA6453}` in this location but I can't find it:

[image]

In the documentation of OpenSTAAD I found this:

[image]

I'm going to give it a try to register OpenSTAAD.

Comment: Clearly the object has not been registered

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How can I register it?

Comment: Typically you register a COM object with regsvr32. What does the documentation say?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I'm currently searching on its documentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found something in the documentation, I added to my question above.

Comment: Well, it was already registered or the ProgId you found would not be present either.  Maybe it isn't actually a 32-bit component, look in HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID.  And watch out with Regsvr32.exe, it must be run from an elevated command prompt and there are two versions of it (32-bit and 64-bit).  Contact the owner for support if you can't figure it out.